# A few detailed questions about SFM and MVS

Tags: computer-vision

I have a few questions about Structure from Motion and Multi-view Stereo hope you can help me. Let's assume we collect 1000 internet photo of a landmark and want to use them to reconstruct the 3D representation of the building. My questions are:

1. In SFM, we need to start with 2 images and incrementally build the sparse reconstruction. How do we find the 2 images from the 1000 we collected?
2. Do we need the camera intrinsic for the two images? For the internet photos, we usually do not know the camera intrinsic. If we do not have them, how can we build the epipolar constrain and solve the rotation and translation between the two images? I read some book and it talked about optimize the camera intrinsic, rotation, and translation at the same time. I am not sure how to do it.
3. After the initial step, we are going to use pnp algorithm to add the third and more images to the incremental reconstruction. If we do not know the camera intrinsic for the 3rd image, can we run Pnp?
4. For MVS, we want to build a dense reconstruction. Let's look at the dense reconstruction from two images. Does dense reconstruction mean we have to search epipolar line to find a match for every pixel in the image?

Thank  you very much.

Comment: What has this to do with the MVS operating system? You used the tag so it must be somewhat related.